Touchpad not working on System76 Ubunut 24.04
I am running a System76 Pangolin with Ubuntu 24.04. I have recently upgraded from Ubunut 23.10, running the upgrade, not a clean install. Shortly after the upgrade, the touchpad stopped working intermittently. I booted to a USB drive and the touchpad still didn't work. The touchpad has worked since, but it is not working now. The touchpad is identified in the Gnome settings.
I got a recommendation from System76, added modprobe and i8042:
/etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash modprobe.blacklist=psmouse i8042.noaux"
sudo update-grub

xinput list
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See
the xinput man page for details. ⎡ Virtual core pointer
id=2    [master pointer  (3)] ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer
id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)] ⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:15
id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)] ⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:15
id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)] ⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:15
id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)] ⎣ Virtual core keyboard
id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ xwayland-keyboard:15                        id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]


sudo lshw   *-input:5
product: PNP0C50:0b 0911:5288 Touchpad
physical id: 6
logical name: input7
logical name: /dev/input/event5
logical name: /dev/input/mouse1
capabilities: i2c


less /proc/but/input/devices I: Bus=0018 Vendor=0911 Product=5288
Version=0100 N: Name="PNP0C50:0b 0911:5288 Touchpad" P:
Phys=i2c-PNP0C50:0b S:
Sysfs=/devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-0/i2c-PNP0C50:0b/0018:0911:5288.0001/input/input7
U: Uniq= H: Handlers=mouse1 event5  B: PROP=5 B: EV=1b B: KEY=e520
30000 0 0 0 0 B: ABS=2e0800000000003 B: MSC=20

It seems that the device is detected, but not active. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Please load Ubuntu 24.04 from a live USB (without installing) and check if the issue is present there. Sometimes, there are issues caused by upgrade which are absent in a fresh install.

I have booted from an Ubuntu 24.04 USB drive and the issue persists. Currently the touchpad is not working, but a new symptom has arisen. When last the touchpad worked, the mouse clicked randomly on its own.
